# Debouncing interrupt using capacitor

Tags: nodemcu, interrupt, debounce, capacitors

I'm currently working on nodeMCU and need to use interrupt pin. I find out there are bouncing problem when using interrupt thus i use capacitor 100uF to solve this problem. **The question is by using multiple interrupt pin, do i need multiple capacitor (one for each pin) or only one for all pin?** The question arise because if I parallel the capacitor it would increase the capacitance and perhaps would create a problem(?)

I using interrupt pin for LM 393 speed encoder [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081W2TY6Q)
(for simplicity, i use switch to describe the encoder pin on schematic)
Basically work like switch but no floating pin since it is a comparator, always between high or low.

Schematic :
[image]

Comment: You are talking about an interrupt being used for some kind of switch closure, correct?

Comment: @timemage input of lm393 encoder

Comment: 4 encoder using 4 different pin as input

Comment: The LM393 is as common **comparator**.  You're saying "encoder".  So this is confusing. Perhaps you should edit the question to link to the thing you're talking about.  And a diagram of what you're doing maybe of what you're proposing as a possible solution that you're asking about.

Comment: sorry for confussions i make, i attach the schematic and some additional info above @timemage

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely clearer.  I had about four different interpretations of it before.  It still doesn't quite make sense as drawn.  Being open collector, the LM393 that is *part* of your encoder boards acts to pull the signal to GND, rather than to VCC as you have modeled.  And It's not clear how the capacitors are supposed to work under the way you've drawn the model.  Just a warning, I'm not sure to what degree others will find this on topic.  So although we may refine the question it may get closed anyway.  We'll see.

Comment: Does the output of the encoder board really show bouncing? Thats normally only with mechanical switches. A ready to use module like you showed shouldn't do that. Or did you just assume, that is bounces?

Comment: the caps go in parallel to the "switches".

Comment: I suggest using a low pass filter where the capacitor is on the micro pin.  You can then add a series resistance to control your debounce time. I do not know the part but are you sure it has internal pull down resistors.